# Powershell replace text in a field from import-csv

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I'm reading in a large **csv** file via `Import-CSV` and have a column of data with the following format; **v00001048**, **v00019045**, or **v0036905**.  I'd like to replace all the zero's (0) after the v but before any number not a zero so the above text becomes; **v-1048**, **v-19045**, or **v-36905**.  Done plenty of searches without successful results.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a CSV (say, 'data.csv') with data like this:

```
Property1,Property2,Property3
SomeText,MoreText,v00001048
```

Then you can replace the leading zeros in `Property3` using this technique:

```
$data = Import-csv .\data.csv 

$data | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Property3 = $_.Property3 -replace "(?<=v)0+(?=\d+)","-"
    }
```

If the property doesn't have any leading zeros to start with (e.g. `v1048`) this will leave it untouched.  If you'd like it to insert the '-' anyway, then change the regex pattern to:

```
"(?<=v)0*(?=\d+)"
```

Comment: And If you dont have headers you can do it like this `Import-Csv .\data.csv -Header A,B,C`  and then use `$_.C` instead of `$_.Property3`

Comment: Works great except if the value is v0047003 it's changed to v-47-3.  I need to keep all zeros on the second "-".

Comment: Odd.  Doesn't do that for me. `v0047003 ` becomes `v-47003` as expected.

Comment: @boxdog , same here, i get also `v-47003` as expected